Need Help Proving a Category is Self-Dual
I am trying to prove that the category Sup (the category of complete partially ordered set with supremum, and functions that preserves supremums) is self dual. But I simply have no idea where to start.
Can someone give me any hints?
Any help is appreciated!

https://mathoverflow.net/a/52210

The trick is that every such poset also admits arbitrary infimums! $\inf S = \sup {x : \forall s \in S (x \leq s)}$. So you can send each poset to its opposite and send each morphism to its adjoint.

@NaïmFavier Thank you! And about that category being well powered? Everywhere I see say that it is a trivially verified condition but it is not that direct to me...
